# Unable to add event listeners to elements rendered after a JSF Ajax update

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsf

I need to add an event listener on paste to all elements with a specific class.

I used this simple javascript:

```
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-inputfield');
```

to get all the elements, and then for each element this one:

```
addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

Where is the problem:

The funtion starts on page load, but at that moment, i don't have all the elements rendered.

When some conditions render another element with that class, this element doesn't have the paste event handled.

I use Primefaces to render or not the elements.

Someone can suggest any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `fields.addEventListener("paste", handlePaste);` You need to assign listener to an object, in this case, your fields object

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I have tried and I got this error in console: fields.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: Can you share your HTML code? and the `handlePaste` function?